# Contact PC from PC or Mac (preferred) not on LAN

Tags: mac, web

I'm going to be doing the website for my church, which is where the server is, but I'd like to be able to access the files from home. Could I do this from my Mac? If so how? If not, how would I do it from my PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a VPN, a **[Virtual Private Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network)**, such as [LogMeIn's](https://secure.logmein.com) free **[Hamachi2](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/)** to the server to access the files.

[Description of a VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network):

> A virtual private network (VPN) is a secure way of connecting to a private Local Area Network at a remote location, using the Internet or any insecure public network to transport the network data packets privately, using encryption.

Works on OSX as well as Windows.

See this how-to [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com) article:

> [Geek to Live: Create your own virtual private network with Hamachi](http://lifehacker.com/201786/geek-to-live--create-your-own-virtual-private-network-with-hamachi)